# Create PostgreSQL table comment using a prepared statement

Tags: sql, ruby, postgresql, sql-injection

Is it possible to prepare a Postgres 'COMMENT ON' statement?

I have a program that allows users to create tables. I'd like to give them the option to add a description of the table's contents. As this data is coming from users, I'd like to use prepared statements.

Using Ruby and the '[pg](http://[pg][1])' gem, I use the below to setup a Postgres connection and example data:

```
table_name  = "test_shakespeare"
description = "Shakespeare's sonnets"

con = PG.connect(
  :dbname   => "poefy",
  :user     => "poefy",
  :password => "poefy"
)

sql = "CREATE TABLE #{table_name} (example TEXT);"
con.exec(sql)
```

Here are my failed approaches, together with the errors they throw.

```
# ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$1" (PG::SyntaxError)
sql = "COMMENT ON TABLE #{table_name} IS $1;"
con.exec(sql, [*description])

# ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$1" (PG::SyntaxError)
sql = "COMMENT ON TABLE #{table_name} IS $1;"
con.prepare("comment", sql)
con.exec_prepared("comment", [*description])

# ERROR:  could not determine data type of parameter $1 (PG::IndeterminateDatatype)
sql = "COMMENT ON TABLE #{table_name} IS '$1';"
con.exec(sql, [*description])

# ERROR:  bind message supplies 1 parameters, but prepared statement "comment" requires 0 (PG::ProtocolViolation)
sql = "COMMENT ON TABLE #{table_name} IS '$1';"
con.prepare("comment", sql)
con.exec_prepared("comment", [*description])
```

It seems that preparation is not possible for this type of statement, and I should resort to SQL string manipulation. That being the case, what is the best way to go about this? The data is not sensitive or critical, and I am only really concerned with correctly represented quote marks and apostrophes.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does appear that this is not possible.

So I went with the old "double all the single quotes" method.

```
safe_desc = description.gsub("'", "''")
con.exec "COMMENT ON TABLE #{table_name} IS '#{safe_desc}';"
```

This feels really hacky. But for now I'm marking it as the answer.

If there's a safer way, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I assume ruby supports same statements as postgres, [which  does it for](http://postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-prepare.html)

> Any SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or VALUES statement

not `COMMENT IS`

Comment: I suspected as much, but thanks for the link to the documentation, that's very helpful.